# Cycloid rolls on another identical Cycloid

Tags: geometry

A common cycloid with parametric equations

$$ x = r  ( t- \sin t - \pi) \, , y= (3+\cos t) r $$

with center point P $(0,4r)$ of its base at beginning of motion  rolls on another identical but fixed cycloid without slipping:

$$ x = r  ( t- \sin t -\pi), \quad  y= (1- \cos t) r $$

Find locus of P.   Sorry about poor quality sketch.

[image: Rolling Cycloid]

Comment: I think you mean the first cycloid to have $x = r(t - sin(t)-\pi)$ as well.

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point $P(t)$ on the second cycloid at parameter $t$, the slope is $\sin(t)/(1-\cos(t))$.  The slope at the corresponding point on the first cycloid is $-\sin(t)/(1-\cos(t))$.  We must translate $Q(t)$ to $P(t)$ and rotate by angle $\theta$ so that the slopes coincide: $\theta = 2 \arctan(\sin(t)/(1-\cos(t)))$.  I get for the path of your point:
$$ r [ \left( t-\pi \right) \cos \left( t \right) +t-\pi-2\,\sin \left( t
 \right) , \left( \pi-t \right) \sin \left( t \right) -2\,\cos \left( 
t \right) +2]
$$

[image]